# Planting and landscaping around a grave

Tags: fruit-trees, plant-recommendations, landscaping, winter-gardening, layout-planning

This is a graveyard in South Asia. My goal is to grow some plants covering the rather bare area. What kind of plants would thrive here? From trees, flowering plants to ground covers. Plus, something to cover the wall in the back. Perhaps a climber? I also plan on setting up a pergola over the graves. I'll need something suitable for that as well.

I'm also allowed to plant outside the barriers of the actual graves, so no restrictions whatsoever.

The climate here is semi-arid. It's quite dry as per the little rainfall we get but since there's a tube-well a few feet away from the site and im making the trip daily, watering isn't an issue.

From experience, flowering plants do really well here. Even some tropical plants. As long as your consistant with the watering.

Soil is too heavy to work with at the moment, but that won't be an issue either as I'm already in the process of amending it all around down to 2 feet. It'll be ready before spring time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to know in what location this graveyard is.

Comment: We'd also need to know what kind of climate you're in, how much rainfall you get, high and low temperatures, how much sunshine, type of soil, and so on before we could even start to make recommendations.

Comment: Hamid, I think this a good improvement. You may also consider breaking it down into separate questions, e.g. one about ground covers, one about trees (don’t forget size here, your space is limited, for example), etc. You can always add links to the other questions to connect them.

Comment: What may also be helpful for our community is if you could mention the kind of plants that grow well in your region. It’s always good to know from where to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot Stephie. You have no idea how much I've benefited from all the advice you've given me here. As far as what grows well here=Roses, oleanders, marigolds, geraniums, carnations, pinks, sweet williams, african daisies, stocks, daffodils. The past year I kept on buying all of these in pots form my local nursery with the aim of getting myself familiar with their needs before bringing them to the site but now I'm confused. Where do I plant what. The right pairing. The right colour scheme etc. Guy like me with no experience, im sure the end product's gonna be awful. Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for your loss. The word "paradise" as a garden comes to us from your part of the world. It is a place we associate with beauty, rest and tranquility, a relief from the cares and worries of normal daily life. If the land is hot then it will have cool breezes, and if the land is dry then it will have evidence of an abundance of water.

You might find it rewarding to start with a plan of what might go into your garden. When you take visitors to the site you may want to associate your chosen plants with events in a life - for example this plant came from the person's home town where he knew it as a child, or another plant because it was part of the floral decoration at a wedding. The stories and associations help to recall the person's life moments.

Build your garden slowly and carefully. Note what does well in the soil; you will not want those plants that show stress, only those that enjoy the location and it might take time to find that mix. Asia is known for its love of roses and rose cultivation that provide both colour and fragrance. In [this article](https://www.ft.com/content/f1b9f768-1635-11e3-a57d-00144feabdc0) there is a discussion of a number of plants that do well in the dry soil. Roses might do well against the wall in the background in well-tended soil. Fruit trees are nice but can be expensive to maintain; figs are often seen as a sign of good and copious water but might call for more water than you can manage, that will be for you to decide.

Herbs of various kinds are well adapted to dry ground, will look happy at times that you cannot water, and will resist dry winds and hot sun. Sages, mints, thyme and oregano will give scented leaves when there are few flowers.

Think of provision of a place to sit, and where the seat should be located. Also, review what plants you see growing locally and happily and try to emulate that situation. Just build up slowly and don't be afraid to be adventurous. Good luck.

Comment: If the soil is truly hard/bad, fruit trees can be difficult and may require deeper holes than feasible? Mature size could also be an issue. (Just a thought...?)

Comment: Colin thanks a lot. This was really useful. I'm really grateful for whay you've done here for me. Plants that ive seen do well here include Roses, oleanders, marigolds, geraniums, carnations, pinks, sweet williams, african daisies, stocks, daffodils. Now comes the hard part, creating art. Choosing where to plant what. The right location, the right combination of plants and colour. I feel like you need to be artist to make gardening work and Im still new to this with a lot to learn. I have most of these plants already in containers ready to be transplanted. What would you do?